# Angular animation with :leave/:enter only seems to do something on page reload

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I think I'm close to have a working angular animation, but right now it doesn't do much :(

Here it is

```
trigger("fadeInOut", [
  transition("* => *", [
    query(":enter", [style({ opacity: 0 })], { optional: true }),
    query(
      ":leave",
      [style({ opacity: 1 }), animate("2s", style({ opacity: 0 }))],
      { optional: true }
    ),
    query(
      ":enter",
      [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate("2s", style({ opacity: 1 }))],
      { optional: true }
    )
  ])
])
```

Just simple fadeIn/fadeOut on add/remove (I think). And here is the HTML

```
<main @fadeInOut class="container">
    <div *ngIf="state">State is true</div>
    <div *ngIf="!state">State is false</div>
</main>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r2bdkc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

As you see, toggling the state will show a different **div** element, but without animation. If you reload you'll see a nice fadeIn effect.

I tried to place the *@fadeInOut** on the **div**s but that didn't help. So there must be something I don't understand about **transition** and/or **query**. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Angular Animations are designed for elements being added or removed from the DOM. So, in this case, main only triggers once on start and that's how it is supposed to work. Can you please elaborate your use case to give a proper solution?

Comment: ok, but what if I place the animation on the DIVs, like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-unqkxq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I still don't get fadeIn's or fadeOut's on leaving/entering elements

Comment: This should be of help https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers and
https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences#complex-sequence

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a `transition` instead of `query`. Below is the modified angular animations code:

```js
trigger("fadeInOut", [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('2s', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('2s', style({ opacity: 0 })),
  ]),
])
```

and you would apply these animations to the `div`s directly instead of its parent

```html
<main class="container">
    <div *ngIf="state" @fadeInOut>State is true</div>
    <div *ngIf="!state" @fadeInOut>State is false</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got a solution, but I think the answer "Angular Animations are designed for elements being added or removed from the DOM" is right.

Start to take the solution of @William Juan

A bit of CSS :

1. Position the class .container as relative
2. Children (the 2 divs) as absolute, with a given top - left - ... value (same values for an overlapping effect)

In your .ts file, use a delay :

```
  trigger("fadeInOut", [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      animate('1s 1s',  style({ opacity: 1 })),
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('1s', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    ]),
  ])
```

This will make the impression of fade in-out.